# Overhead of returning reference to member variable data

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am new to C++ and get confused about what goes on under the hood when a class method returns a reference to a member variable that is raw data (rather than a pointer or a reference). Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Dog {
    int age;
};

class Wrapper {
public:
    Dog myDog;

    Dog& operator*() { return myDog; }
    Dog* operator->() { return &myDog; }
};

int main() {
    auto w = Wrapper();

    // Method 1
    w.myDog.age = 1;
    cout << w.myDog.age << "\n";

    // Method 2
    (*w).age = 2;
    cout << w.myDog.age << "\n";

    // Method 3
    w->age = 3;
    cout << w.myDog.age << "\n";
}
```

My question is: what happens at runtime when the code reads `(*w)` or `w->` (as in the `main` function)? Does it compute the address of the `myDog` field every time it sees `(*it)` or `it->`? Is there overhead to either of these two access methods compared to accessing `myDog_` directly?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a VERY large amount of code in your post for a pretty specific question.   Please make sure to post a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*.  Also, why are you worried about the behavior of what the compiler does when it sees something?  That doesn't seem relevant to anything unless you're asking about compile times.  Compilers don't really see addresses, anyhow.  They aren't available until runtime at which point the compiler is long gone.

Comment: All methods will be equivalent. At assembly level, a reference is just a pointer.

Comment: To clarify, is it guaranteed that the pointer location is computed at compile-time rather than at runtime? Because one interpretation of the `operator->()` code is that the address of `myDog` is computed at runtime, right?

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks for the feedback. I replaced the code sample with a shorter one, and clarified the question. I'm asking about runtime performance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Technically, what you are asking is entirely system/compiler-specific. As a practicable matter, a pointer and a reference are identical in implementation.

No rational compiler is going to treat

```
(*x).y
```

and

```
x->y
```

differently. Under the covers both usually appears in assembly language as something like

```
y(Rn)
```

Where Rn is a register holding the address of x and y is the offset of y into the structure.

The problem is that C++ is built upon C which in turn is the most f*&*) *p programming language ever devised. The reference construct is a work around to C's inept method of passing parameters.